# weather overlay for google maps

Tags: google-maps

Does there exist a good way to make a weather overlay ( for US ) in **google maps v3**?

if nothing like that exists now, maybe there is a service that will give you coordinates of major storm systems and i could place icons on the map

OR

if weather overlay is not to be had, what about a **weather advisories** overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for weather services that provide regularly updated kml file and fetch that kml data onto your map or GE plugin. Something like that maybe: http://wdssii.nssl.noaa.gov/ or http://www.srh.noaa.gov/geospatial/kmlpage.htm